# There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 1 ...]

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, bulkinsert, stringbuilder

I tried using stringbuilder to make the process simpler but it is showing error and I don't understand whether the problem is with the stringbuilder or code syntax.

code:

```
        if (dataGridView4.RowCount == 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Attendance form is empty");
        }
        else
        {
            //string att;
            int a = dataGridView4.RowCount;
            string[] s = new string[a];
            for (int i = 0; i < a; i++)
            {
                if (dataGridView4.Rows[i].Cells[1].Selected)
                {
                    s[i] = "Present";
                }
                else
                {
                    s[i] = "Absent";
                }
            }
            string[] s1 = new string[a];
            for (int i = 0; i < a; i++)
            {
                s1[i] = dataGridView4.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
            }
            string date = dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
            StringBuilder command = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < a; i++)
            {
                command.Append("INSERT into Attendance (att_date, emp_code, is_present) values ('" + date + "','" + s1[i] + "','" + s[i] + "')");
            }
            SqlCeConnection conn = new SqlCeConnection(@"Data Source=C:\Users\admin\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\hotel.sdf");
            conn.Open();
            SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand(command.ToString(),conn);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show("Attendance Added");
```

Please help me solve this error, also if you have any suggestion to make the above code simpler please let me know.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I just noticed, I am using sql server compact, am I getting the error because of this? should I use for loop instead of stringbuilder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use parameters to avoid sql injection attacks and also you don't need to convert to string like what you did to date time parameter..

```
using (SqlCeConnection con = new SqlCeConnection(strConn))
{
    con.Open();
    using (SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand("insert into Attendance (att_date, emp_code, is_present) values (@att_date, @emp_code, @is_present)", con))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@att_date", dateTimePicker1.Value);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@emp_code", emp_codeVal); //s1[i]
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@is_present", is_presentVal); //s[i]
        cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

If you have many records to insert then try to use [`SqlCeResultSet`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlserverce.sqlceresultset%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), You can check the MSDN example code given on that link.

For each grid row you can do the following

```
// this is only a sample you need to write for your table 
SqlCeUpdatableRecord rec = rs.CreateRecord();

rec.SetInt32(0, 34);
rec.SetDecimal(1, (decimal)44.66);
rec.SetString(2, "Sample text");

rs.Insert(rec);
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me out. I need to insert multiple rows to database, do I have to for loop your code or is there any way to use stringbuilder with your code?

Comment: In your code: att_date, emp_code, is_present, based on my code I should use @date, s1[i], s[i] and dateVal, s1[i]Val, s[i]Val right?

Comment: it should be `dateTimePicker1.Value, s1[i], s[i]`